# QMetaMethod from member function pointer

Tags: c++, qt

Given a pointer to a method of a `QObject` derived class: Is there a way of getting the `QMetaMethod` of the method the pointer is pointing to? I am basically looking for a function like `QMetaMethod::fromSignal`, but for slots.

---

*Note:*
I tried getting the index through `static_metacall` with `QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod` and using that for `QMetaObject::method`:

```
void(Class::*method)() = &Class::method;
int methodIndex = -1;
void *metaArgs[] = {&methodIndex, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&method)};
const QMetaObject mo = Class::staticMetaObject;
mo.static_metacall(QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod, 0, metaArgs);
qDebug() << methodIndex;
// QMetaMethod mm = mo.method(methodIndex)
```

The output is always -1.

Comment: I can't see any functions for doing what you want. Consider posting a question about what you want to achieve more generally to see if there is a different solution. It is often best to leave the Qt Meta system alone unless there is no other way of doing things.

Comment: The `moc` generated code does not implement the `IndexOfMethod` metacall for non-signal methods. Consider submitting a patch to Qt. See [qtbase/src/tools/moc/generator.cpp](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/19d289ab1b5bde3e136765e5432b5c7d004df3a4:src/tools/moc/generator.cpp#L1324).

Comment: you have very strange need. Why you need `QMetaMethod` from pointer to signal? Signals should be emitted only from object it self, so your case is very strange and suspicious.

Comment: @MarekR I do not need a `QMetaMethod` from a pointer to a signal (that would be easy anyway since there is `QMetaMethod::fromSignal`). I need a `QMetaMethod` from a pointer to a slot. I am using that for RPC. At the moment i am providing my remoteCall method with a string of the name of the function that should be called. Using a pointer to get the `QMetaMethod` would make it both more elegant and enable compile time type checking of the arguments and the return type.

Comment: See [QTBUG-36861](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36861), the Qt devs don't seem to want this. What exactly do you want to do with the `QMetaMethod`?

Comment: @Oktalist I want to do remote procedure calls to another machine sharing the same code. For serializing the call I am putting the method name followed by all the argument values in a QByteArray. At the moment I am providing the method name as a string. For compile time type checking I would like to use a method with the folling signature to do the remote calls:
`template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
auto remoteCall(R(C::*method)(Args...), Args... args) -> R { ... }`
But in that I don't know how to get the method name from the method pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, the only solution is to modify `moc`. The patch is rather trivial, though:

```
diff --git a/src/tools/moc/generator.cpp b/src/tools/moc/generator.cpp
index d831edf..7dcefcc 100644
--- a/src/tools/moc/generator.cpp
+++ b/src/tools/moc/generator.cpp
@@ -1311,15 +1311,12 @@ void Generator::generateStaticMetacall()
             isUsed_a = true;
         }

-    }
-    if (!cdef->signalList.isEmpty()) {
-        Q_ASSERT(needElse); // if there is signal, there was method.
         fprintf(out, " else if (_c == QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod) {\n");
         fprintf(out, "        int *result = reinterpret_cast<int *>(_a[0]);\n");
         fprintf(out, "        void **func = reinterpret_cast<void **>(_a[1]);\n");
         bool anythingUsed = false;
-        for (int methodindex = 0; methodindex < cdef->signalList.size(); ++methodindex) {
-            const FunctionDef &f = cdef->signalList.at(methodindex);
+        for (int methodindex = 0; methodindex < methodList.size(); ++methodindex) {
+            const FunctionDef &f = methodList.at(methodindex);
             if (f.wasCloned || !f.inPrivateClass.isEmpty() || f.isStatic)
                 continue;
             anythingUsed = true;
```

The following then works as expected:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/metamethod-lookup-24577095
#include <QtCore>

class MyObject : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_SLOT void aSlot() {}
   Q_SLOT void aSlot2(int) {}
   Q_SLOT int aSlot3(int) { return 0; }
   Q_SIGNAL void aSignal();
   Q_SIGNAL void aSignal2(int);
};

template <typename Func> int indexOfMethod(Func method)
{
   using FuncType = QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>;
   int methodIndex = -1;
   void *metaArgs[] = {&methodIndex, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&method)};
   auto mo = FuncType::Object::staticMetaObject;
   mo.static_metacall(QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod, 0, metaArgs);
   return methodIndex;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   qDebug() << indexOfMethod(&MyObject::aSlot)
            << indexOfMethod(&MyObject::aSlot3) << indexOfMethod(&MyObject::aSignal2);
   return 0;
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Did you submit that patch to Qt? I am asking because otherwise i might. Or do you think it is not a good idea to include that in the public Qt version?

Comment: Feel free to submit it. I have no time at the moment.

Comment: Since Qt uses git, it's very, very simple to have a bunch of your own patches riding on top of releases. They simply are rebased (brought forward) every time you bump up to another tag, and one has to fix occasional conflicts. git is quite helpful here.