# Functionpointer based syntax for QMetaObject invokeMethod

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I'm working on a simple wrapper for a IPC lib we are using.

I want to convert the events from this lib to calls on Qt slots.

Right now i have something like this:

```
void Caller::registerCallback(int id, QObject* reciever, const char* member)
{
    _callbackMap[id] = std::make_pair(reciever, QString(member));
}

bool Caller::call(const SomeData data)
{
    auto reciever = _callbackMap.value(data.id);

    return QMetaObject::invokeMethod(reciever.first, reciever.second.toLocal8Bit(), Qt::QueuedConnection, 
        QGenericReturnArgument(),
        Q_ARG(SomeData, data));
}
```

```
void Receiver::someCallback(SomeData data)
{
    qDebug() << data.str;
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Caller caller;
    Receiver reciever;

    caller.registerCallback(1, &reciever, "someCallback");

    caller.call(SomeData({ "Hi", 1 }));

    return a.exec();
}
```

```
struct SomeData {
    QString str;
    int id;
}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SomeData);
```

This works quite well. But I don't like to register the callbacks as strings. I would prefer a compile time checking with a syntax like this:

```
caller.registerCallback(1, &reciever, &Reciever::someCallback);
```

I am aware of [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-4) implementation.

The slots I want to register always have exactly one argument and no return value.

I already found [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36861) request what could solve my problem but unfortunately this was never implemented.
Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577095/qmetamethod-from-member-function-pointer) doesn't help me as I'm not able to patch the moc we are using.

So is this really not possible with all the meta magic Qt is using?

---

EDIT:

I found a solution that works also when the Caller dose not know about the Receiver (what is actually what I need):

```
//Caller.h

class Caller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Caller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Caller();

    //void registerCallback(int id, QObject* reciever, const char *member);
    template < class R, typename Func >
    void inline registerCallback(int id, R reciever, Func callback)
    {
        using std::placeholders::_1;
        registerCallbackImpl(id, reciever, std::bind(callback, reciever, _1));
    };

    bool call(const SomeData);

private:
    QMap<int, std::pair<QObject *, std::function<void(SomeData)>> > _callbackMap;

    void registerCallbackImpl(int id, QObject* reciever, std::function<void(SomeData)> callback);
};
```

```
//Caller.cpp
void Caller::registerCallbackImpl(int id, QObject* reciever, std::function<void(SomeData)> callback)
{
    _callbackMap[id] = std::make_pair(reciever, callback);
}

bool Caller::call(const SomeData data)
{
    auto reciever = _callbackMap.value(data.id).first;
    auto fn = _callbackMap.value(data.id).second;

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(reciever, [reciever, fn, data]() {
        std::invoke(fn, data);
        fn(data);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    return true;
}
```

```
//main.cpp

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Caller caller;
    Receiver reciever;

    using std::placeholders::_1;

    caller.registerCallback(2, &reciever, &Receiver::someCallback);

    caller.call(SomeData({ "Hi2", 2 }));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In Qt 5.x there is `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` function's overload that accepts a pointer to a function (slot). Did you try to use it?

Comment: Yes, this overload only accepts functions without arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This soulution relies upon std::invoke and lambda.

Variant 1: use std::invoke directly instead of QMetaObject::invoke

Variant 2: use std::invoke inside a lambda, which is passed to QMetaObject::invoke

Variant 3: use MACRO instead of std::invoke in variant 2.

If you use QMetaObject::invoke you've got an option to choose connection type - Direct or Queued. In variant 1 the call is invoked immediately like in direct connection.

receiver.h

```
#ifndef RECEIVER_H
#define RECEIVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

struct SomeData {
    QString str;
    int id;
};
//Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SomeData);

class Receiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Receiver(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    void doSmth(SomeData data) {
        qDebug() << data.str;
    }

signals:

};

#endif // RECEIVER_H
```

caller.h

```
#ifndef CALLER_H
#define CALLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

#include "receiver.h"
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object)->*(ptrToMember))
typedef void (Receiver::*callback)(SomeData);

class Caller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Caller(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }

    void registerCallback(int id, Receiver* receiver, callback c)
    {
        auto pair = std::make_pair(receiver, c);
        _callbackMap.emplace(id, pair);
    }

    bool call(const SomeData data)
    {
        auto &receiver = _callbackMap.at(data.id);
        return QMetaObject::invokeMethod(receiver.first, [data, receiver] () {
            // method 1
            std::invoke(receiver.second, receiver.first, data);
            // method 2 (better not to use a MACRO)
            CALL_MEMBER_FN(receiver.first, receiver.second)(data);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }

    bool call_invoke(const SomeData data)
    {
        auto &receiver = _callbackMap.at(data.id);
        std::invoke(receiver.second, receiver.first, data);
        return true;
    }

signals:

private:
    std::map<int,std::pair<Receiver*,callback>> _callbackMap;
};

#endif // CALLER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "receiver.h"
#include "caller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Caller caller;
    Receiver reciever;

    caller.registerCallback(1, &reciever, &Receiver::doSmth);
    caller.registerCallback(2, &reciever, &Receiver::doSmth);
    caller.call(SomeData({ "Hi", 1 }));
    caller.call_invoke(SomeData({ "Hi2", 2 }));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Variant 2 is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach might be to use a suitable `std::function` to capture the callback and then make use of `QTimer::singleShot` with a zero timeout to invoke the callback in the correct context.

```
struct SomeData {
    QString str;
    int     id;
};

class Caller {
public:
    using task = std::function<void(SomeData)>;

    void registerCallback (int id, QObject *receiver, task t)
    {
        _callbackMap[id] = std::make_pair(receiver, t);
    }
    bool call (SomeData data)
    {
        auto receiver = _callbackMap.value(data.id);
        QTimer::singleShot(0, receiver.first, [=](){ receiver.second(data); });
        return true;
    }
private:
    QMap<int, std::pair<QObject *, task>> _callbackMap;
};

class Receiver: public QObject {
public:
    void someCallback (SomeData data)
    {
        qDebug() << data.str;
    }
};
```

Then use as...

```
Caller caller;
Receiver receiver;

caller.registerCallback(1, &receiver, [&](SomeData d){ receiver.someCallback(d); });

caller.call(SomeData({ "Hi", 1 }));
```